# Is there any way to change the splash screen in flutter every time user opens it

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Hello there so I have a set of images which I want it to bee shown in the splash screen in my flutter app every time user opens it. But what I want is that every time the user opens it a random new image as a splash screen is shown..
Is there anyway to achieve it?

Comment: Are you using native splash or flutter splash?

Comment: I wanna know if it is possible doesn't matter which splash I'd use, I can use any if I can achieve it

Comment: @amir_a14 currently Its flutter splash in my app

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible, use example below:

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SplashScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  SplashScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  final images = [
    "assets/img1.jpg",
    "assets/img2.jpg",
    "assets/img3.jpg",
    "assets/img4.jpg",
    //...
  ];
  late final index = Random().nextInt(images.length);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Image.asset(images[index]),
    );
  }
}
```